# What is the difference of Pooled ByteBuf and UnPooled ByteBuf

Tags: netty

Under `package io.netty.buffer`, there exists many types of `ByteBuf`, such as `PooledDirectByteBuf`, `PooledHeapByteBuf`, `UnpooledDirectByteBuf`, `UnpooledHeapByteBuf`. Could anyone kindly explain their difference?

Answer (score 5):

Pooled ByteBuf are what they name says... They are pooled which means they are not released directly but pooled so they can be reused again. This is mainly useful as allocating and deallocating of direct ByteBuf is expensive.